# Android:apply a same look and feel to all version of android?

Tags: android

Here I am explaining entire apps, I have created  ActionBar from ActionBar Style Generator and added that style into my apps. I am using SherLockLibrary to support all android version. I did apply style from manifest file like android:theme="@style/Theme.Customtheme". but what happen look and feel of ui is different on version having >3.0 and different on version having <3.0 you can see in following fig.2 and fig.3. I want same look and feel to all version of 
android. i was wrote my own style in manifest but not showing same look and feel. In my apps there are four classes first activity which extend SherlockFragmentActivity and other two is fragement which extend SherlockListFragment.

anybody have another option to do above stuff and please provide me good solution to solve compatibility and look and feel issue of android version.
I goggled lot and I had asked question on stackoverflow 2 time but not got proper answer. it may happen I was not able to ask perfect question so I hope somebody give me perfect answer. 
Thanks in advance

Here i am attaching look and feel. 
fig.1 original style which I want,
fig.2 view on 4.2 version,
fig.3 view on 2.3.3 version

[image]

following is the manifest file

```
<activity
     android:name="com.example.customactivity.CustomActivity"
     android:label="@string/projects"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.Customtheme" >
            .
            .
```

following is the layout for stacked tab

```
 <TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
          />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            />
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Following is the main activity code

```
public class CustomActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
TabHost tHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);

        tHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tHost.setup();

        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
                ResidentialFragment resdentialFragment = (ResidentialFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("residential");
                CommercialFragment commercialFragment = (CommercialFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("commercial");
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                if (resdentialFragment!=null) {
                    ft.detach(resdentialFragment);
                }       
                /** Detaches the commercialfragment if exists */
                if (commercialFragment!=null) {
                    ft.detach(commercialFragment);
                }
                /** If current tab is residential */
                if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("residential")){

                    if(resdentialFragment==null){
                        /** Create residentialFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new ResidentialFragment(), "residential");
                    }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(resdentialFragment);
                    }

                }else{    /** If current tab is apple */
                    if(commercialFragment==null){
                        /** Create AppleFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new CommercialFragment(), "commercial");
                     }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(commercialFragment);
                    }
                }
                ft.commit();
            }
        };

        /** Setting tabchangelistener for the tab */
        tHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);

        /** Defining tab builder for residential tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecResidential = tHost.newTabSpec("residential");
        tSpecResidential.setIndicator("Residential");
        tSpecResidential.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecResidential);

        /** Defining tab builder for commercial tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecComm = tHost.newTabSpec("commercial");
        tSpecComm.setIndicator("Commercial");
        tSpecComm.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecComm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this? and tabhost has been depricated. use Action bar tabs. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-android/

Ofcourse to support in all versions,replace the above as sherlock activity.

Comment: TabHost is NOT deprecated. TabActivity is. You can use either Action Bar tabs or TabHost